# How to create a left section for half of the document

Tags: lists

I want to create document like presented below. How do I go about it?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`paracol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/paracol). It's fairly straight-forward:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol,lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

%\columnratio{0.5} 50/50 split between columns
\raggedright
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \textbf{Study Name (Number):}
  \switchcolumn
  MarginProbe System US Post-Market Study
  \switchcolumn*
  \textbf{Product:}
  \switchcolumn
  MarginProbe System
  \switchcolumn*
  \textbf{Indication:}
  \switchcolumn
  \underline{Intended Use:} \par
  \lipsum[2]
\end{paracol}

\columnratio{0.3}% First column takes up 30% of \textwidth
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \textbf{Study Name (Number):}
  \switchcolumn
  MarginProbe System US Post-Market Study
  \switchcolumn*
  \textbf{Product:}
  \switchcolumn
  MarginProbe System
  \switchcolumn*
  \textbf{Indication:}
  \switchcolumn
  \underline{Intended Use:} \par
  \lipsum[2]
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a `description` or a `longtable` environment:

[image]

The size of the columns can be adjusted via setting such as `labelwidth=5.0cm` or changing the `p{}` setting in the `longtable` environment to obtain:

[image]

---

### Code: `description`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[labelwidth=\widthof{\bfseries Study Name (Number):}, leftmargin=!, noitemsep]
  \item [Study Name (Number):]
      MarginProbe System US Post-Market Study
  \item [Product:]
      MarginProbe System
  \item [Indication:]
      \underline{Intended Use:} \par
      \lipsum[2]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

### Code: `description` with column size control:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[labelwidth=5.0cm, leftmargin=!, noitemsep]
  \item [Study Name (Number):]
      MarginProbe System US Post-Market Study
  \item [Product:]
      MarginProbe System
  \item [Indication:]
      \underline{Intended Use:} \par
      \lipsum[2]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: `longtable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\raggedright
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{4.5cm} p{\dimexpr\linewidth-4.5cm-2\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}
  \textbf{Study Name (Number):} &
      MarginProbe System US Post-Market Study \\
  \textbf{Product:} &
      MarginProbe System \\
  \textbf{Indication:} &
      \underline{Intended Use:} \par
      \lipsum[2]
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```